# How to use Ctrl-R_= with :execute

Tags: vim

I'm trying to get an expression on a variable expanded on a `:execute` command. I've guessed this could be achieved by using `Ctrl-R_=`, but it is not clear how the special characters should be inserted. None of the following worked:

```
exec 'echo ^R=1+1^M'
exec "echo <ctrl-r>=1+1<cr>"
```

The purpose is set a global variable used as an option in a plugin to select how to show the results. It is used on an `:execute` command, and works fine for 'vsplit' or 'split'. But the choice between vertical or horizontal split sometimes depends on the window layout. In order to do this without adding extra complexity to the plugin I've thought of something like the following:

```
let var = '<ctrl-r>=(winwidth(0) > 160 ? "vsplit" : "split")<cr>'
```

---

**Edit**

Currently the plugin has something like the following:

```
exec 'pluginCommands' . g:splitCmd . ' morePluginCommands'
```

The `g:splitCmd` is a plugin option, which works for when set with "split", "vsplit", "tabe", etc. My intent is to change this fixed behavior, setting `g:splitCmd` in such a way that it represents an expression on the `execute` above, instead of a fixed string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that I'm understanding the issue better, I think a dynamic re-evaluation inside the config var is impossible if the variable's value is inserted in an `:execute g:pluginconf . 'split'` statement. To achieve that, you'd need another nested `:execute`, or switch to command-line mode via `:normal! :...`; both approaches will fail on the appended `. 'split'`, because you can't add quoting around that.

The way I would solve this is by prepending a `:help :map-expr` to the plugin's mapping; change

```
:nmap <Leader>x <Plug>Plugin
```

to

```
:nnoremap <expr> <SID>(PluginInterceptor) PluginInterceptor()
:nmap <Leader>x <SID>(PluginInterceptor)<Plug>Plugin
```

Now, you're get called before the mapping is executed, and can influence the plugin config there:

```
fun! PluginInterceptor()
    let g:plugconf = winwidth(0) > 160 ? "vsplit" : "split"
    return ''
endfun
```

If modifying the plugin mapping is for some reason difficult, you could also trigger the `PluginInterceptor()` function via `:autocmd`; for this particular case e.g. on `WinEnter` events.

Comment: It is not hard to change the plugin mapping, nor the plugin line itself. The point was to avoid clutter the plugin with code/sub-options that few people would use. As it is not possible to do this directly on the config var, your approach on the mapping seems to be the better one.

Comment: Thanks! I've used this "trick" of prepending an expression mapping several times myself.

Answer (score 1):

With `:execute`, you already have a way to evaluate expressions; just move them out of the static strings to get them evaluated:

```
exec 'echo ' . 1+1
```

The `<C-R>` only works in command-line mode (and insert mode), so only within a `:cnoremap ...` command (or with `:normal`). (And even there, you can use `:map <expr>`, which often gives you simpler code.)

Comment: Indeed, this would not need Ctrl-r_= if the code was moved outside the static string. The problem is that the `:execute` is part of a plugin, and I'm trying to avoid changing it. To do this it would be necessary to tinker on the variable used on the execute, but maybe it isn't possible.

Comment: You should add this crucial information to the question; i.e. all constraints and the exact integration problem!

Comment: Have you read the "The purpose is set a.." on the question? If yes, please let me know how it was still unclear, so I can improve my english :)

Comment: So the plugin uses something like `:execute g:pluginconf . 'split'`, and you want to dynamically re-evaluate the `g:pluginconf`, right?! Your question hints at it, but at least for me (and apparently also benjifisher) it was too subtle.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want is simply

```
:let var = (winwidth(0) > 160) ? "vsplit" : "split"
```

Comment: Not exactly; this would set var to "vsplit" or "split", depending on the window where this variable is set. I'm trying to achieve a "vsplit" or "split" depending on the window layout when the plugin *uses* the variable, thus executing split on a small window, and vsplit on a wider one.

Comment: My line will set `var` depending on the current value of `winwidth(0)`.  If you enter my line interactively on the command line, that means the current window.  If your plugin executes the line as part of a function, autocommand, etc., then it will depend on the current window when the plugin is executing.

Comment: It will change on the command line or autocommand, indeed. I had thought on the usual form of setting a plugin option, which is only `:let` a global variable on the .vimrc. But if it is not possible, setting it on autocommand is probably the better alternative. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like

```
exec 'pluginCommands' . eval(g:splitCmd) . ' morePluginCommands'
```

should work just fine, and is a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: This should work indeed, but requires changing the plugin. I was trying to do it without changes. Ctrl-r= would do if it worked inside the execute. It would be nice to have this expansion for various options on different plugins, without changing any of them.